# What is boot.js (dart)

Tags: dart

I have seen that `boot.js` is used in combination with polymer in dart. What happened to dart.js?

What is this boot.js?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>index</title>
    <script src='packages/polymer/boot.js'></script>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, the `boot.js` script makes it possible to load and run a polymer.dart app
without needing to compile your app using `build.dart`. You can still run `build.dart` as a lint tool, but there is no required compile step anymore.

Internally, `boot.js` looks for the imported files with `<polymer-element>`s, collects them, and initializes each `<polymer-element>` for you. Read the description at the top of file if you want to know more about the internals. You can find it under `packages/polymer` of any polymer app.